# Mass moment of inertia for a rectangular plate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

Can someone show me the mass moment of inertia derivation for a rectangular plate? I was able to figure out the derivation for the area moment of inertia yielding $$I=\frac{bh^3}{12}.$$ How do I translate this to the mass moment of inertia?

Comment: Area moment and mass moment of inertia are different concepts used in different analysis. Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Where is your axis of rotation, and what is its direction?

Comment: About what axis you want the MMOI?

Answer (score 0):

(a) You are, I assume, talking about the moment of inertia about a line through the centre of the plate and parallel to the edge of length $b$.

(a) All you need to do is to multiply by $\sigma$, the mass per unit area. Thus $$I=\sigma \tfrac1{12}bh^3$$
$\sigma$ enters into your calculation as a multiplied constant before integration, as you need the mass, $\sigma b\ dx$, of each strip rather than its area, $b\ dx$.

If the mass of the whole plate is $m$, then clearly $\sigma =\frac m{bh}$, so we can write
$$I= \tfrac1{12}mh^2$$
You'll notice that in this version the breadth '$b$' of the plate doesn't feature. It's the same equation as for the moment of inertia of a rod of length $h$ and mass $m$ about a perpendicular axis through its centre. Can you see why this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Area moment is irrelevant to the mass moment of inertia calculation.

Looking at a rotation about one edge of the plate with cross sectional area $A$ use the following formulas

$$ m = \int_0^\ell \rho A {\rm d}x $$
$$ {\rm I}_{zz} = \int_0^\ell \rho A x^2 {\rm d}x $$

Which results in ${\rm I}_{zz} = \frac{m}{3} \ell^2 $

If you want to consider the slices through the plate with $y = -\tfrac{h}{2} \ldots \tfrac{h}{2}$, and area $A=w h$.

$$ m = \int_0^\ell \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} \rho w {\rm d}y {\rm d}x $$
$$ {\rm I}_{zz} = \int_0^\ell  \int_{-h/2}^{h/2} \rho w (x^2+y^2) {\rm d}y {\rm d}x $$

Which results in ${\rm I}_{zz} = \frac{m}{3} \ell^2 + \frac{m}{12} h^2$. Note that $  \ell^2  \gg  h^2 $ the the simpler expression is a good approximation.